# Keycloak is not maintaining session in browser

Tags: java, keycloak

I am using keycloak(4.3.0) openid-connect flow. For my client app, I am using:

```
public class AuthenticationTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String KEYCLOAK_JSON = Constants.KC_CONFIG_JSON_PATH;
    InputStream config = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(KEYCLOAK_JSON);
    KeycloakInstalled keycloak;

    try {
        keycloak = new KeycloakInstalled(config);
        config.close();
        keycloak.loginDesktop();

        AccessToken token = keycloak.getToken();
        System.out.printf("UserId: %s%n", token.getSubject());
        System.out.printf("Username: %s%n", token.getPreferredUsername());
        System.out.printf("Email: %s%n", token.getEmail());

        System.out.println(keycloak.getTokenString());          
        System.in.read();
    } catch (IOException | VerificationException | OAuthErrorException | URISyntaxException | HttpFailure
            | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

}

I have referred the example mentioned here: https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/ca16080145d226e50628d5696ffb9508

First time I launch the application and login, I get

> "Login Successful.You may close this browser window and go back to
>   your console application."

However, if I launch second instance of my application/ relaunch my application even without closing the previous browser window , still the login page appears instead of **you are already logged in** message.

(The new login page is appearing in a new tab on the same window as the first login page, so it is not an issue of failure to maintain state across different windows. Also I have tried relaunching the app withing 20 seconds so it does not seem t be an issue of timeout either)

Browser: Firefox, chrome.

Any idea what I am doing wrong. Expectation is that browser must maintain a keycloak session for the same user until closed for at least a few minutes.

NOTE: I did not face this issue in Keycloak 3.4.3. But it started coming on 4.1.0 and 4.3.0

I see follwing difference in cookies on 3.4.3 and 4.x:

**3.4.3: (same whther first login or subsequent login)**

[image]

**4.x First time login:**
[image]

**4.x Subsequent login:** (an addition KC_RESTART cookie is seen)
[image]